# Passing non-string parameters to Jenkins JJB builder templates

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins JJB template, where I would like to customize `triggers` per job instance. This approach would have worked great if `triggers` was a string parameter, but it requires an object. How can I pass an object (in this case - an array) to the job template?

```
- job-template:
    name: 'my-template-{proj}'
    trigger_overrides: []

    # The obj: syntax should have worked,
    # but it doesn't handle the default from above
    triggers: '{obj:trigger_overrides}'


- project:
    name: my-project
    jobs:

      # for this job, customize triggers
      - 'my-template':
          proj: A
          trigger_overrides:
            - github
            - timed: "@daily"

      # this job should use the default triggers
      - 'my-template':
          proj: B
```

Note that in case triggers is always passed in, the empty triggers doesn't work. The global default overrides template parameter:

```
- defaults:
    name: global
    triggers:
      - github

- job-template:
    name: 'my-template-{proj}'
    triggers: '{obj:trigger_overrides}'

- project:
    name: my-project
    jobs:
      - 'my-template':
          proj: A
          trigger_overrides: []
```

Neither does this work (empty array is given as a default):

```
triggers: '{obj:trigger_overrides|[]}
```

P.S. This issue was also filed with [jjb devs](https://storyboard.openstack.org/#!/story/2003442)

Answer (score 0):

You want to refer to how `gerrit_release_trigger_file_paths` is handled here in the releng/builder repository for passing a list:
https://github.com/opendaylight/releng-builder/blob/master/jjb/lf-infra/lf-infra-jobs.yaml#L120-L130

The original template is implemented in releng-global-jjb repository here: https://github.com/lfit/releng-global-jjb/blob/master/jjb/lf-docker-jobs.yaml#L229

JJB Best Practices:
https://docs.releng.linuxfoundation.org/projects/global-jjb/en/latest/best-practices.html

```
- project:
   name: my-project
   jobs:
     - 'my-template':
          proj: A
          trigger_overrides:
              - trigger_a
              - trigger_b
              - trigger_c
```